# Problem with cut() in R

Tags: r, cut

I want to assign subjects to classes based on probabilities that I provide. I will be doing this in a variety of cases, with different values. Sometimes, I want the probability of a particular class to be 0.  I've been using

```
classlist <- cut(runif(p), c(0, pdrop, ptitrate, pcomplete, pnoise, 1), labels = c("D", "T", "C", "N", "O"))
```

but this fails when two of the p variables are the same.  I could make them different by minimal amounts e.g. pdrop = .2 ptitrate = .200001.  But is there some better way?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Care to provide a fully functional dummy example?

Comment: If you want to do it this way, the p values should represent the breaks in a cumulative probablity scale, and therefore should never be the same unless there is a zero probability for a class - in which case there is no point including it. But caracal's sample suggestion is a better method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest `sample()`:

```
> p         <- 100
> groups    <- c("D", "T", "C", "N", "O")
> probVec   <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.05)
> classlist <- factor(sample(groups, size=p, replace=TRUE, prob=probVec))
> table(classlist)
classlist
 C  D  N  O  T 
26 16 28  5 25
```

Comment: That gives me an error message that there is a non positive probability.
I ran
pdrop = .1;  ptitrate = .5;  pcomplete = 0; pnoise = .2 ; pother = 1 - (pdrop + pcomplete + pnoise + pother);  #PROBS OF DIFFERENT CLASSES 
p         <- 100
groups    <- c("D", "T", "C", "N", "O")
probVec   <- c(pdrop, ptitrate, pcomplete, pnoise, pother)
classlist <- factor(sample(groups, size=p, replace=TRUE, prob=probVec))
table(classlist)

and got an error.

Error in sample(groups, size = p, replace = TRUE, prob = probVec) : 
  non-positive probability

Comment: @Peter: You've created `pother` as a function of itself.  I suspect you meant `pother = 1-(pdrop+ptitrate+pcomplete+pnoise)`.  Is that the source of your error?

Comment: Sorry about format of that comment.  Is there a way to format comments?